# Angular 1.5 CORS

Tags: angularjs, cors

I have an angular js client that makes requests to a server. My http provider (at http://localhost) code looks like this:

```
angular.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    // Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request:
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common  = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post    = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put     = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch   = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);
```

At the server side (at http://localhost:3000 , so just the port is different), I return the headers back with a perl script in Mojolicious like this:

```
# Set response headers so that we can send cross-domain requests
$self->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => $self->req->headers->header('origin'));
$self->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true');
$self->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
$self->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token');
$self->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '1728000');
```

Now, this code works perfectly in Angular 1.2. However, when I try to upgrade to Angular 1.5, things stop working. When looking at my logs and firebug, the server is accessed, the right scripts are executed, the server returns the correct values, the browser (tested with both firefox and chrome) simply ignores everything that is sent back, including any error codes. The problem seems to happen with Angular 1.4 as well.

Did something change in the meantime with Angular? Is there some extra code that needs to be run for it to accept Cross-Domain requests?

Comment: In old angular versions the result had been clean data from server.
In new version it return xhr object, described:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

That is why it is possible to

Comment: `things change` ... what specifically are the differences when you inspect actual requests?

Comment: When I inspect the requests with firebug, their caption is in a red font, just like with an error. There is only the headers-tab when you expand them, and that only contains the request headers, not the response headers. I also do not see any error code or response whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of headaches I figured out what the problem was. It turns out it doesn't have anything to do with CORS in the end, but I'm posting it here in the hope that anyone else with a similar problem while upgrading will find it useful:

In my website, users identify with session cookies. I have a piece of code that checks whether an authentication cookie exists, and if it doesn't then it immediately redirects back to the login page.

The code I used was:

```
navigationModule.controller( 'NavigationController', ['$scope', '$cookies', 
    function( $scope, $cookies ){
        if(!$cookies.auth) {
            window.location = '/login.html';
        }
    }  
]);
```

And as it turns out, from Angular version 1.2 to 1.5, the syntax for accessing the cookies was changed. So my if-statement would always return false, redirecting immediately, explaining why the requests were cut off so sudden. In the past I had a lot of trouble with CORS-requests, which displayed similar behaviour of not returning any helpful error messages when something went wrong, so I mistakenly chalked it up to that.

The code that fixed the problem:

```
navigationModule.controller( 'NavigationController', ['$scope', '$cookies', 
    function( $scope, $cookies ){
        if(!$cookies.get('auth')) {
            window.location = '/login.html';
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think angular don't check CORS. It just send http request and return the result at promise resolve method.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0-rc.1/src/ng/http.js#L1245
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0-rc.1/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L101

Comment: So if that's not the problem, are there any reasons why an upgrade from Angular 1.2 to 1.5 would result in the browser just declaring server requests invalid?